# @model dynamic binding with arrays

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a data class that I want to show via a View, allow the User to change it, and bring it back in via data binding. I want to do this via @model dynamic. Is this possible?

This is my model

```
public class MyData
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
```

Getting sent to a view like so

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyData[] myDataList = new MyData[2];
        myDataList[0] = new MyData() { A = 2, B = "Fred" };
        myDataList[1] = new MyData() { A = 3, B = "Sue" };

        dynamic charts = (from ch in myDataList
                          select new
                          {
                              ch.A,
                              ch.B
                          }).AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.ToExpando());

        return View(charts);
    }
```

With the view like so (this is wrong)

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

@foreach (dynamic item in Model)
{
    <text>
    @Html.TextBox("item.B")
    </text>
}
```

I'm floundering a bit here as I don't know if this is even possible and I can't find many complex examples of @model dynamic

To be clear, this example is an academic one, what I want here is to understand what's possible with dynamic models in asp mvc

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth would you want to use `@model IEnumerable<dynamic>`?

Comment: "this example is an academic one, what I want here is to understand what's possible with dynamic models in asp mvc"

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your view:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Lenght; i++)
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].A)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].B)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, although I did say I wanted to use @model dynamic I didn't include it in the code, I have done now

Answer (score 0):

While you can get it to work, I wouldn't recommend it.

The simple fix IMHO is to use the `ExpandoObject` as `model` directly. There's no point in converting it to `dynamic` at all.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is get a complete roundtripped example of using '@model dynamic' as it's something new to me.

Comment: The point is that it may be new to you, but this is *not* a good way to play with it. Frankly, let me save you trouble and just say don't even bother with `dynamic` at all. It has its purposes, but those don't really extend past what the MVC framework needs. If you're using it in your own code, dimes to dollars you're writing bad code.